# Why does the reflected rays gets deviated by angle $2\theta$ if spherical mirror is rotated by angle $\theta$?

Tags: optics, reflection

[image]

In the question, I don’t know why the reflecting angle will be $2\theta$, when the mirror is titled at angle $\theta$.

Comment: I am 90% sure this was asked before, have you tried searching?

Comment: This happens with planar mirrors too. If the angle of incidence is $\theta$, the angle between the incoming and outgoing rays is $2\theta$. It's just geometry.

Answer (score 0):

Light comes in along the line, at an angle $\theta$ below the normal (dashed line), and is reflected at the same angle $\theta$ above the normal. Two $\theta$s gives $2\theta$.